# System V Message Queues - getting message that already exists

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

I've been working on a project and one of the tasks that I have to do is passing the string received from another process through a pipe to yet another process but this time I have to use a message queue.

I've managed to learn how `msgqueue` works and made a simple working program but, the thing is, it works when receiving a string from `stdin` through `fgets`.

My question is:

Can I pass a string that is already saved in other variable (for example 
`char s[20] = "message test";` ) to the msgqueues mtext?

My simple program looks like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct msgbuf {
    long    mtype;         
    char string[20];
};
struct msgbuf mbuf;
int open_queue( key_t keyval ) {
    int     qid;

    if((qid = msgget( keyval, IPC_CREAT | 0660 )) == -1)
        return(-1);

    return(qid);
}

int send_message( int qid){
    int result, size;



    size = sizeof mbuf.string;
    if((result = msgsnd( qid, &mbuf, size, 0)) == -1)
          return(-1);

    return(result);
}

int remove_queue( int qid ){
    if( msgctl( qid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1)
        return(-1);

    return(0);
}

int read_message( int qid, long type){
    int     result, size;


    size = sizeof mbuf.string;      

    if((result = msgrcv( qid, &mbuf, size, type,  0)) == -1)
        return(-1);

    return(result);
}

int main(void){
    int    qid;
    key_t  msgkey;
    msgkey = ftok(".", 'm');
    if(( qid = open_queue( msgkey)) == -1) {
        perror("openErr");
        exit(1);
    }

    mbuf.mtype   = 1; 
    fgets(mbuf.string, sizeof mbuf.string, stdin);

    if((send_message( qid)) == -1) {
        perror("sendErr");
        exit(1);
    }


    mbuf.mtype   = 1;       

    if((read_message(qid, mbuf.mtype))== -1){
        perror("recERR");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Queue: %s\n", mbuf.string);
    remove_queue(qid);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use the System V message queue implementation?  POSIX message queues provide a somewhat cleaner API.

Comment: In any case, why do you suppose there would be any problem with doing what you describe?  Did you read something in `msgsnd()`'s docs that makes you think so?  You *did* read its docs, right?

Comment: Yeah, I have to use System V.
To be honest I had a hard time understanding manual description so I was using some internet guide to get a touch how it is working.
According to your question:
I was trying to run it with something like that: 

`char s[20] = "test";`
`mbuf.string = *s;`

But it had error during compiling with these result:

 incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[20]’ from type ‘char’

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to ask about the error you actually encountered than to ask a tangentially related question about a speculative explanation for that error?

Comment: Well, I thought it would be better to ask for the outcome I want to achieve, sorry if I made it a bit tangled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses `fgets()` to fill the buffer `mbuf.string` with input read from stdin. You can instead use something like `strcpy(mbuf.string, "message test")` where you can pass in a variable or use a hard coded string.

I recommend using the POSIX message queue API as the System V API is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, but this is not responsive to the actual question.

Comment: Actually, this is what I was hoping to achieve, sorry if I made it a bit unclear, but this is the first time I'm actually asking for advice and I'm not good at explaining what I need so far.
Anyway, thank you for help.
By the way, should I worry about this warrning?
`warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘str`

Comment: Make sure to `#include <string.h>` at the top of your file.